# Drawing a tournament bracket (PHP & GD)

Tags: php, gd, leaderboard

I'm currently working on drawing a tournament bracket for one of my projects.  It seems to be working drawing smaller brackets but once I get to 16 it starts acting up.

Follow through the links, and see how it falls out of place after 8.

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/2

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/4

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/8

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/16

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/32

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/64

http://www.mattdsworld.com/mmaplayer/index.php/tournament/viewBracket/128

After that I get out of ram errors, which isn't really an issue since its legitimate use of ram, and I can justify raising the maximums for this script (of course, it won't run every page load in the final script,the image will be cached).

Anyways, As you can see if you progress through the images, they seem to get more and more off track.

The code is here:
http://pastebin.com/f5485b027
(should I be posting code like this, or inline?  I wasn't sure)

I am completely lost as to how to fix this, so please input ideas/suggestions.  I don't need a code solution, I just need guidance on the math/positioning.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are "correctly" drawn based on the algorithm.

Did you step through the code for the problem cases especially for $y?

i'm not sure how the algo works (don't really understand the use of the $takeAway).

But this is what i would come up with:

```
for ($k = 1; $k < ($rounds + 1); $k++)
{
    // Calculate currLeftDraw and currRightDraw Here...

    $spacing = 60 * pow(2, ($k - 1));
    $firstY = ($spacing / 2) - 30;

    for ($i = 0; $i < ($sizePlayers / (pow(2, $k))); $i++)
    {
        $yPos = $firstY + ($i * $spacing);

        // Rest of code here...
    }
}
```